# Python Pandas Selecting a Single Dataframe Column and Keeping as Dataframe instead of Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some work where I'm referencing a single column of a dataframe and the doing other operations with it (e.g., merging).

When I select a dataframe column I find that I constantly have to change it back to a dataframe to merge or perform some other type of operation.

Is there a way to keep a single column a dataframe?

Example

```
df1

      astigmatism    nearsighted    glasses
Roy      2.0            yes         monofocal
Mary     0.0            no          plain
Peter    1.0            yes         bifocal
```

and

```
df2

       height     weight     haircolor

Roy     72         159        brown
Mary    60         110        brown
Peter   65         130        black
```

I want to merge `df1['glasses']` on to `df2`:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1['glasses'], how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

this gives me an error:

```
 {ValueError}can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

but if I do this:

```
 df3 = df2.merge(pandas.DataFrame(df1['glasses']), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

it works and I get desired result:

df3

```
       height     weight     haircolor  glasses

Roy     72         159        brown     monofocal
Mary    60         110        brown     plain
Peter   65         130        black     bifocal
```

I'm wondering if there is a systematic way to avoid having to avoid having to redefine the series as a dataframe and to just have that series be a one column dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df1[['glasses']]`

Comment: Use `df1[['glasses']]`

Comment: df2[['glasses']]=df1['glasses'] no need to merge

Comment: Oh, and shameless plug... since you seem to be doing some merging, perhaps you would like to understand more about the API? I have written a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), you may like to take a look.

Comment: @W-B is this true if the indices don't overlap (e.g, df1.index != df2.index?

Comment: @coldspeed - no shame in the plug ;)  Its a great primer.